# The link carrying data from api call with subscribe is binding only after refreshing the URL

Tags: html, angular, api, url, typeerror

I have created in Angular with component,a url link which takes data from api from backend with subscribe method. When I use the url in browser it should be bind (display) the data in the browser respective to Html component. If I paste the URL once in the browser , it is loading correctly(data loading correctly). When I paste the same URL in another page , it is not binding with page showing TypeError:Unable to read properties undefined. But when I refresh the link then data is binding correctly.The same url binding correctly only once , when using again and again it binds only after refreshing. How to solve this.

I tried to find the logic , but there is no problem

Answer (score 2):

You get the data async, which means the property is undefined while the request is not completed. Within that time you can't access it. Sometimes the request finishes fast and doesn't try to access the object while undefined. Other times the request is slow and leads to the error. It is a race condition then.

```
this.myApiService.getData().subscribe(data => this.data = data);
```

Hence in template either use ngIf

```
<ng-container *ngIf="data">
  <div>{{ data.someProperty }}</div>
  <div>{{ data.someOtherProperty }}</div>
</ng-container>
```

or safe access operator

```
  <div>{{ data?.someProperty }}</div>
  <div>{{ data?.someOtherProperty }}</div>
```

In ts file do the same with if and safe access operator to prevent undefined access.